# how to find the largest and 2nd largest in array through functions in c++.?

Tags: c++, arrays

i am beginner in c++ and trying to find largest,2nd largest and 3rd largest in array using functions

```
if(array[i]>array[i+1])
{
    cout<<"A is largest ="<<a<<endl;
}
else
{
    cout<<"invaild"<<endl;
}
```

Is it possible to do it with if else or i use swap,how to use that

Comment: It is important to define the term "the second largest number". For example if you have array int a[] = { 2, 2, 1 }; then what is the second largest number 2 or 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code ,ask questions if you dont understand the logic

```
       #include<iostream>
                using namespace std;
                int main()
                {
                    int array[5],largest,fbig,sbig,temp;
                    for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
                    {
                      cout<<"enter the value"<<endl;
                      cin>>array[i];
                    }
                    cout<<"The values are "<<endl;
                    for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
                    {
                        cout<<array[i]<<" ";
                    }
                    cout<<endl;
                    fbig=array[0];
                    sbig=array[1];
                    if(sbig>fbig)
                    {
                        temp=sbig;
                        sbig=fbig;
                        fbig=temp;
                    }
                    for(int i=3;i<=5;i++)
                    {
                        if(array[i]>fbig)
                        {
                            sbig=fbig;
                            fbig=array[i];
                        }
                        else if(array[i]>sbig)
                        {
                            sbig=array[i];
                        }
                    }
                    cout<<"The first big is "<<fbig<<"and the second big is        
                "<<sbig<<endl;
                }
```